# Microsoft CRM 2011 and cross browser support

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Does CRM 2011 have cross browser support?  Or does it still require Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit 04/02/2013**.  Cross browser support begins with CRM 2011 Update Rollup 12.  The browsers supported are listed at: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784954](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669061)

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669061 to see support by product (CRM 4/CRM 2011) and rollup.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, no other browser than IE is supported for the full webclient (yet). See the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web client software requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979184.aspx).

However the mobile front-end "Mobile Express" which is part of Dynamics CRM 2011 is accessible with other browsers. Simply append `/m`to your url, for example `https://crm.foobar.org/m`

Answer (score 3):

Still need IE, however you can use IE9 (which does legacy support).

Or can do what I do, use Chrome, but use the IETab plugin (which mocks IE). Then I don't have to have 100 thousand CRM windows open.

Answer (score 3):

Cross browser support wont happen until HTML 5 is used.

I think this is planned for CRM 2012 or CRM 6.

They mentioned this in the CRM statement of direction which you can read about here
http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/crm-statement-of-direction-crm-6-release-date-q2-2012/