# Microsoft Dynamics CRM always Mobile Express

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

When i login to my Dynamics CRM from my desktop web browser or anywhere else it redirects me to the Mobile express view. How can i disable it ?

Comment: Would you please include more facts to your question: which browser, which CRM version, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably because you are not using Internet Explorer.

CRM 4 - IE only.

CRM 2011 - Currently IE only - but soon'ish it will be multi browser.

[Microsoft CRM 2011 and cross browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803844/microsoft-crm-2011-and-cross-browser-support)

Comment: And when it goes multi-browser, IE7 will no longer be supported, it's 8-10 only.

Comment: @AdamV It **will** be supporting IE10. It's not doing it yet. Not officially and not fully (which I had the great anti-joy of discovering since I'm using Win8 and **have to** go with IE10, since I don't like using virtual machines). :)